# How to have optional request model properties in ASP.NET Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a ASP.NET Web API 2 project. I've created a request model that contains properties that will be the input to my API. For GET requests, I enumerate the properties in the method's parameter list, and for POST request, I have the Request object as the sole parameter.

How can I specify optional properties in my Request object? I would like to specify "Count" as an optional parameter of the request model. Would this do the trick?

For POST methods:

```
class Request{
public int id {get;set;}
public int? Count{get;set;}
}
```

For GET methods:

```
public Response MyActionMethod(int id, int? Count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't you tried it yourself, before posting the question?

Yes, this would do the trick. More proper examples:

```
[HttpPost]    
virtual object Foo([FromBody] Request req);

// query parameters (as object)
[HttpGet]
virtual object Foo([FromUri] Request req);

// query parameters (as arguments)
[HttpGet]
virtual object Foo(int id, int? count = null);

//uri + query parameters
[HttpGet]
[Route('/path/:id')]
virtual object Foo(int id, int? count = null);
```

Instead of `int?` you can just use `int`, then `0` is the default value in Object `Request`, and for the method arguments, you should set the default value yourself `int count = 0`.

Comment: Is it okay if I set the default value in the constructor of the Request object? I'm not sure if that would mess with the [HttpPost] one.

Comment: Yes, you can set values in the `constructor`, the binder will then overwrite the value if it is present in `message body` / `query argument`.